# PHP, shell_exec and an input

Tags: php, input, shell-exec

is it possible for shell_exec to execute a given command, where the initial command would ask the for a dynamic input then followed by a command that's based on the input itself.

i've researched for hours for the answer and i can't seem to find what i'm looking for.

i have a requirement that's similar to the idea of the example below and any help would be appreciated since

`$x = shell_exec("read -p 'Enter your name : ' x; echo 'Your name is' : $x");`

echoing x outputs :

*your name is*

as you can see i'm running multiple commands, but i do not know where i can insert inside the string command for the input.

note : 
i tried doing

`$x = shell_exec("echo 'Foo' | read -p 'Enter your name : ' x; echo 'Your name is :' $x");`

`echo $x;`

output was :

*Your name is :*

i was expecting like

**Your name is : Foo**

clearly, something is wrong.

Comment: what shell commands do you actully want to run ?

Comment: you need to escape `$x` inside the string `$x = shell_exec("read -p 'Enter your name : ' x; echo 'Your name is' : \$x");`

Comment: i tried adding \ after the $x, 
the output was 
"your name is : $x"

Comment: @Dagon

it's pretty long, related to fabric script (python) and php, basically, the idea is after i run that script, the server will ask me for a user password after the initial shell command, this has to be run from php because i will be supplying dynamic data to the command (concat variables to the command string)

Answer (score 1):

I've come across the same problem as you with `read` other times. If you execute the same line on the terminal, the result is the same, so this is not a php issue, but a shell issue:

```
$ echo 'Foo' | read -p 'Enter your name : ' x; echo "Your name is : $x"
Your name is :
```

If you wrap the `read` inside a `while .. do .. done`, then it all works perfectly:

```
$ echo 'Foo' | while read -p 'Enter your name : ' x; do echo "Your name is : $x" ; done
Your name is : Foo
```

I don't know why this happens though.

Also you can try using [`proc_open`](http://php.net/proc-open) and similar, and you'll get more control of the input/output streams, but I don't know whether they will work with the `read` issue.

Comment: / mogria

your combined suggestions have gave me the answer, with a lil trial and error,

$x = shell_exec("echo 'foo' | while read -p 'enter your name : ' x; do echo 'your name is : ' \$x; done;");

echo $x;

has produced what i needed.

thanks guys